# EXCEL:multiple IF function can solve?

Tags: excel, if-statement

Hi I have encountered a problem and I do not know how to solve:

Clients deposited in four types of currencies: SGD, EUR, HKD and USD. I need to find out the amount to be credited to them (Column D). 
The credit condition are:

1. If they deposit less or equal to USD2000, they are credited with **15%** of their deposit.
2. If they deposit more than USD2000, their credit will be capped at USD300.
3. For currencies other than USD, I have to do a conversion, and the conversion table is below for your reference. It is based on USD2000 deposit for USD300 credit.

Sample data:

```
    A      B                    C               D
    1    Currency          Initial Deposit    Credit Amount          
    2      SGD                 2650          (Should be G2, since C2>f3)  
    3      EUR                 3000          (Should be G4, since C3>f4)
    4      HKD                 200           (Should be C4*0.15, since C4<f5)
    5      USD                 790           (Should be C5*0.15)
```

Conversion table:

```
         E          F             G
1    Currency    Deposit       Credit
2      USD        2000          300
3      SGD        2540          381
4      EUR        1580          237
5      HKD       15520          2328
```

I do not want to use filter as the list is continuously expanding at the moment. Any one can help? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since the credits are in the deposited currency, a simple VLOOKUP to determine the maximum credit is all you need:

```
=MIN(15%*B2,VLOOKUP(A2,ConversionTbl,3,FALSE))
```